# Return a parent entity together with its child entities using LINQ method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

NET Core web API project, and there is one Get action method that returns an entity(Keyfield) when passing in an id. I would like to modify this method so that it returns the same entity but now together with its children entities(Referencefields). How can I get this within the same call to the database using LINQ method syntax inside this Get method?

My get method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<KeyField>> GetKeyField(int id)
{
   var keyField = await _context.KeyFields.FindAsync(id);

   if (keyField == null)
   {
            return NotFound();
   }

   return keyField;
}
```

My two classes:

```
public class KeyField
{
    public int KeyFieldId { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }

    public List<ReferenceField> ReferenceFields { get; set; }
```

The child entity:

```
public class ReferenceField
{
    public int ReferenceFieldId { get; set; }
    public int KeyFieldId { get; set; }
    public virtual KeyField KeyField { get; set; }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<KeyField>> GetKeyField(int id)
{
   var keyField = await _context.Set<KeyField>()
                         .Where(x => x.KeyFieldId == id)
                         .Include(x => x.ReferenceFields)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

   if (keyField == null)
   {
            return NotFound();
   }

   return keyField;
}
```

Or enable [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) as another option.